# liquid shopify - change number of products displayed on a page

Tags: shopify, liquid, assign, pagination

I would like to change the number of products displayed on a page in shopify, after the user click on the button.

However nothing happens after I click on the button.

Is it because the liquid  cannot be rendered in a script tag?

```
// set 25 products display on the page by default 
{% assign number = 25 %} 
{% paginate collection.products by number %}

<div>
   // content of products description go here
</div>

//after user click on the button, it will change the number of products displayed on a page  

<span><strong>Show&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong></span>
  <button onclick="view()">50&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </button>  
  <span>100&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span> 
  <span>All</span> 
{% endpaginate %}

<script>
    //after user click on the button, it will change the number of products displayed on a page to 5 items. 
   // However Nothing happens after I click on the button.   
    function view(){
        {% assign number = 5 %} 
        {% paginate collection.products by 5 %}
        {% endpaginate %}
    }
```

Comment: Liquid is a template language and you can't update it with javascript.

Comment: Do you know how to reload the template when user click on the button?

Comment: Hide products with pure JS when the user clicks the button. And when he reach 25 just make an AJAX request and grab the next 25.

Comment: Will i have cross domain error, if I render the ajax inside the shopify liquid code? because it seems that shopify has its own server, and I am calling another server which might produce cross domain error

Comment: Why not implement infinite scroll on click?

Answer (score 1):

You should do it using different templates.

Create several collection templates like

collection.12.liquid
collection.24.liquid
collection.48.liquid

in these templates, put the content of collection.liquid and paginate products as 12, 24 and 48

then put a link with these pages like

```
<div>
  Show: 
  <a href="{{collection.url}}?view=12">12</a>
  <a href="{{collection.url}}?view=24">24</a>
  <a href="{{collection.url}}?view=48">48</a>
</div>
```

Using `?view=` yiu will load the template 12, 24, or 48 where you paginate products by 12, 24, or 48

Comment: Hello from the future! This simple solution is remarkably hard to find. Thank you!